# HTML, clickable diagram with boxes appearing on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to build a clickable person diagram where when you click on a person's limb a textbox appears next to the person explaining the selected limb.

The person is on the left, and the boxes stack overeach other on the right. When the limbs are selected it appears as highlighted.

What is the best approach for this? Should I make use of the jQuery toggle?:

`$( "#effect" ).toggle( selectedEffect, options, 500 );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have your Person diagram with an ID of "person-diagram". You should also add a class of "limb" to every element you wish your textbox to appear.

Then, I would bind a jQuery event handler to using jQuery Bind http://api.jquery.com/bind/.
Then, toggle the textbox with jQuery toggle. As far as how to determine what text to show inside the textbox, there are a few different ways you can achieve that. One simple way is to give a title attribute to all your limbs, and then retrieve the title of the limb clicked on and set that as the text in your textbox.

Example:

```
$( "#person-diagram .limb" ).bind( "click", function() {
  $("#textbox" ).toggle();
});
```

That should get you started :)